# How to use Vue without changing path when loading view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, frontend, vue-router

I am creating an addon for Firefox using Vue.js. I want it to have routes for multiple components. However, every time I click on a link from router

`<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>`

I am changing url in browser (so it looks like this ugly one `moz-extension://a86771fb-409f-4096-8a07-b000de29d6bf/dist/index.html#/about`).

Is there any way to prevent from that and leave the search/url bar empty? I can already say that I can use solution different than vue-router if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d recommend not using Vue Router, and instead adding some simple logic to your App component.

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script>
import 'About' from './components/About.vue'
import 'Home' from './components/Home.vue'
import 'NotFound' from './components/NotFound.vue'

const routeMap = {
  about: About,
  home: Home
}

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      page: 'home'
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentView () {
      let component = routeMap[this.page.toLowerCase()]
      if (component) return component
      return NotFound
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="currentView" />
    <button @click="page = 'about'">About</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

You’d probably need to externalize the `page` so that it could be changed from any component, or you could add an event listener to the `<component>` element in your App template that changes the page.

Comment: How to externalize the state: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that - changing URL and managing history is whole point of Vue router. Maybe you can use Vue [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) instead ?